# How to use triple quotes?

Tags: python, string, variables, quote

some variables are being printed wrong.

```
    gv_sixTries = '''
___________.._______ 
| .__________))______|
| | / /      ||
| |/ /       ||
| | /        ||.-''.
| |/         |/  _  \
| |          ||  `/,|
| |          (\\`_.'
| |         .-`--'.
| |        /Y . . Y\
| |       // |   | \\
| |      //  | . |  \\
| |     ')   |   |   (`
| |          ||'||
| |          || ||
| |          || ||
| |          || ||
| |         / | | \
| |         `-' `-'      
| |                      
| |                      
: :                        
. .                      
'''
```

the variable is being printed like that:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLgTU.png)
OS: Windows 10

interpreter: Python IDLE 3.7.2

Comment: Seems like you are missing newline characters on those distorted lines

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prefix an `r` to your string

```
gv_sixTries = r'''
    ___________.._______ 
    | .__________))______|
    | | / /      ||
    | |/ /       ||
    | | /        ||.-''.
    | |/         |/  _  \
    | |          ||  `/,|
    | |          (\\`_.'
    | |         .-`--'.
    | |        /Y . . Y\
    | |       // |   | \\
    | |      //  | . |  \\
    | |     ')   |   |   (`
    | |          ||'||
    | |          || ||
    | |          || ||
    | |          || ||
    | |         / | | \
    | |         `-' `-'      
    | |                      
    | |                      
    : :                        
    . .                      
    '''
```

This tells python to use the string a raw literal, not using backslashes as escape characters

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from unwanted escaping of new line characters due to antislashes at the end of some lines.

Simply declare a raw string by prefixing your string by `r`, and it will fix the problem.

```
gv_sixTries = r'''
___________.._______ 
| .__________))______|
| | / /      ||
| |/ /       ||
| | /        ||.-''.
| |/         |/  _  \
| |          ||  `/,|
| |          (\\`_.'
| |         .-`--'.
| |        /Y . . Y\
| |       // |   | \\
| |      //  | . |  \\
| |     ')   |   |   (`
| |          ||'||
| |          || ||
| |          || ||
| |          || ||
| |         / | | \
| |         `-' `-'      
| |                      
| |                      
: :                        
. .                      
'''
```

Answer (score 0):

The error comes due to a backslash character in the string which is used for printing escape sequence characters(\n, \t, \, etc.). Use raw string for printing a backslash character on the screen, something like:

```
gv_Tries = r"""
___________.._______
| .__________))______|
| | / /      ||
| |/ /       ||
| | /        ||.-''.
| |/         |/  _  \
| |          ||  `/,|
| |          (\\`_.'
| |         .-`--'.
| |        /Y . . Y\
| |       // |   | \\
| |      //  | . |  \\
| |     ')   |   |   (`
| |          ||'||
| |          || ||
| |          || ||
| |          || ||
| |         / | | \
| |         `-' `-'
| |
| |
: :
. .
"""
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because some of your lines end with the Python escape character: `\`.

> The backslash (\) character is used to escape characters that otherwise have a special meaning, such as newline, backslash itself, or the quote character.
>
> *[String and Bytes literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html)*

When a line ends with a backslash, it tells Python that the line is continued on the next line.

```
if some_condition \
    or some_other_condition:
```

To counter this, you either want to 'double up' your backslashes to escape your escape characters:

```
gv_sixTries = '''
| |        /Y . . Y\\
| |       // |   | \\\\
| |      //  | . |  \\\\
'''
```

Or mark your string with an `r` to mark it as a *raw string*.

> Both string and bytes literals may optionally be prefixed with a letter `'r'` or `'R'`; such strings are called raw strings and treat backslashes as literal characters.
>
> *[String and Bytes literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html)*

```
gv_sixTries = r'''
| |        /Y . . Y\
| |       // |   | \\
| |      //  | . |  \\
'''
```